# Best way to implicitly free unmanaged resources in a C# struct?

Tags: c#

Please consider the following code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO
{
    public UInt32       cbSize;
    public IntPtr       Index;
    public UInt32       SubjectChoice;
    public IntPtr       SignerFileOrBlobInfo;

    public SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO(UInt32 _Index, SIGNER_FILE_INFO _SignerFileInfo)
    {
        cbSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf<SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO>();
        Index = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<UInt32>());
        Marshal.WriteInt32(Index, (int)_Index);
        SubjectChoice = SIGNER_SUBJECT_FILE;
        SignerFileOrBlobInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<SIGNER_FILE_INFO>());
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(_SignerFileInfo, SignerFileOrBlobInfo, false);
    }
}
```

For the sake of simplicity of the code using this structure I wrote the above constructor which does the initialization and marshaling for `IntPtr` members, and the structure itself will be marshaled and passed to the native API.

Given that the C# `struct` cannot have a destructor or a finalizer, and given that the GC can't know how those two `IntPtr` fields were allocated and automatically free them I see two possible solutions:

**Solution 1 (Explicit release)**

```
public struct SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO
{
    // ...
    public void Release()
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Index);
        Index = IntPtr.Zero;
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(SignerFileOrBlobInfo);
        SignerFileOrBlobInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
//
// Usage example:
//
SIGNER_FILE_INFO sfi = new SIGNER_FILE_INFO(Filename);
SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO ssi = new SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO(0, sfi);
// ...
ssi.Release();
```

**Solution 2 (Semi-implicit release)**

```
public struct SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO : IDisposable
{
    // ...
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Index);
        Index = IntPtr.Zero;
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(SignerFileOrBlobInfo);
        SignerFileOrBlobInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
//
// Usage example:
//
SIGNER_FILE_INFO sfi = new SIGNER_FILE_INFO(Filename);
using (SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO ssi = new SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO(0, sfi)) {
    // ...
}
```

Perhaps there is another solution (fully implicit cleanup) that I am missing?

I read about `SafeHandle` being recommended over `IntPtr`, but I am not sure whether that could be applied here and how.

Comment: The `using` version seems to be best. But ideally you would let the marshaller do it all automatically by using `class` object references (here you would probably need a `class` with a single `int` field for the `index`, and change `SIGNER_FILE_INFO` to a `class` also) Side note: you don't need to check for `IntPtr.Zero` when you free, `FreeHGlobal` just ignores it in that case

Comment: @Charlieface Good catch about `IntPtr.Zero`, I missed that in Remarks section of the method. I edited the code to not promote doing that. As for using a class that is an option of course, but if I am not mistaken classes have memory allocation overhead compared to structs, shouldn't that be avoided in cases like marshaling?

Comment: `AllocHGlobal` also has overhead, and I would be hard pressed to say whether it's more performant to use the HGlobal heap as opposed to the managed heap. If the class is fully blittable then no extra copying is done anyway. And honestly I wouldn't worry about that sort of performance impact unless you are running a tight loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version with an `IDisposable` is the much better option, as it encourages you to use a `using` for correct error handling (preventing memory leaks).

But you are much better off just using classes for the embedded pointers, and allowing the marshaller to handle everything for you.

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO
{
    int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO>();
    public INDEX Index;
    public uint SubjectChoice = SIGNER_SUBJECT_FILE;
    public SIGNER_FILE_INFO SignerFileOrBlobInfo;

    public SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO(uint index, SIGNER_FILE_INFO signerFileInfo)
    {
        Index = new INDEX{Index = index};
        SignerFileOrBlobInfo = signerFileInfo;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class INDEX
{
    public uint Index;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public class SIGNER_FILE_INFO
{
    int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<SIGNER_FILE_INFO>();
    public string pwszFileName;
    public SafeFileHandle hFile;

    public SIGNER_FILE_INFO(string fileName, SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
    {
        pwszFileName = fileName;
        hFile = fileHandle
    }
}
```

I wouldn't worry about performance here: the difference is going to be miniscule except in very tight loops, and likely than not this version is actually faster (as the marshaller can allocate directly on the stack).

Comment: So `public INDEX Index;` would store a reference to the class `INDEX` in `SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO`, but would that really be automatically marshaled to IntPtr which points to a `DWORD`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what I meant is an `IntPtr` which points to a `DWORD` embedded in the class. Didn't mean to imply type of the pointer itself.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what happens. If all the types are blittable then AFAIK no copying is done, just pinning, as object references are internally stored as pointers anyway

Comment: Before I accept the answer, can you please clarify what would happen if one of the classes (say `SIGNER_FILE_INFO`) has `IntPtr` member which represents native handle not allocated in the class itself but set from outside code?

Comment: I tested this, and I can't get it to work. I am getting `System.AccessViolationException`. I will see if I can get it to work with simpler code and get back to you.

Comment: Nothing will *happen* in that case, it's just a pointer sized integer. What you do with that integer is your department, the marshaller knows nothing about it. There's nothing complex about this code (your other versions are far more complex) but I can't help you unless you can show me the original C struct definitions. I suggest you make a new question for that though.

Comment: Documentation for the structures involved is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signer-subject-info). I just removed blob from the union because I don't need it and didn't want to mess with `FieldOffset` and `unsafe` to deal with it.

Comment: I am calling [SignerSign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signersign) with it, but I think that's entirely irrelevant to the question I asked. I have working code and when I just replace manually marshaled `IntPtr Index` with your suggested `INDEX Index` I am getting invalid argument error so I don't think that method can work, at least not with Win32 API.

Comment: Judging from the docs it looks like it maybe should be either `null` or `new INDEX{Index = 0};` instead of `new INDEX{Index = index};`. No it's not irrelevant to the question: there may be other issues with your `DllImport` declaration.

Comment: There aren't other issues with my `DllImport` because the code works when I marshal everything manually. My question was about the best way of implicit releasing of unmanaged pointers, not about specific problem solution. I guess I should have used simpler example.